# Laravel multi tenancy switching issue

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I have a situation. I have an application that has both admin and tenants. In admin we have modules like user management, tenant management etc. In tenants I have user management and some other modules.
 In `AppServiceProvider` I have set the default connection as tenant as mentioned in [this link](https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.3/connections#forcing-the-connection) (Only after this the tenant login worked). When I create a tenant via admin, I switch the connection as mentioned in [this link](https://laravel-tenancy.com/docs/hyn/5.3/creating-tenants#switch-to-new-tenant) to the newly created customer  and create a user using the default **`User`** Model. This User model is the default one and I have not used the tenant connection trait in this. This created a new user in the tenant database as expected.  But when I tried to switch the connection in another controller, the switch did not work until I used another `CustomerUser` model with the tenant trait. When I used the default User model, the data fetched was from the system. The only difference I found was the code just above the switching, which is,

```php
$website = new Website;
$website->uuid = $customer->domain_name;
app(WebsiteRepository::class)->create($website);
$hostname = new Hostname;
$serverName = $request->server->get('SERVER_NAME');
$hostname->fqdn = $website->uuid.'.'.$serverName;
$hostname = app(HostnameRepository::class)->create($hostname);
app(HostnameRepository::class)->attach($hostname, $website);
return $website->id;
```

I use this returned website id to switch to the tenant.

But when I tried in the other controller the switching code was same but to get the website I used this code:

```php
$customerWebsite = Customers::findOrFail($customerId)->website;
$uuid = $customerWebsite->uuid;
$website = app(WebsiteRepository::class)->findByUuid($uuid);
```

The common switch code:

```php
$tenancy = app(Environment::class);
$tenancy->tenant($website);
```

Please suggest a way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet can be used to configure the app:

```
app(Environment::class)->tenant($hostname->website);
config(['database.default' => 'tenant']);
```